# RDS instance engine name versus pricing get-products databaseEngine name

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds, aws-cli

I am trying to get the pricing info for RDS instances. The problem I have is that I get the instances from the aws-sdk with '**rds describe-db-instances**' which returns me an engine name of the format:

- aurora-mysql
- aurora-postgresql
- custom-oracle-ee
- db2-ae
- db2-se
- mariadb
- mysql
- oracle-ee
- oracle-ee-cdb
- oracle-se2
- oracle-se2-cdb
- postgres
- sqlserver-ee
- sqlserver-se
- sqlserver-ex
- sqlserver-web

however when trying to use the **aws pricing get-products** api the expected databaseEngine filter string needs to be one of these:

- Aurora MySQL
- Aurora PostgreSQL
- Db2
- MariaDB
- MySQL
- Oracle
- PostgreSQL
- SQL Server

On top of that there are different editions for some of the DBs, for example Oracle has oracle-ee or oracle-se2, which can be filtered with the databaseEdition filter.

Now my question is does a mapping for this already exist? I know I could create a custom mapping on my end that converts the engine name to the correct string and gets the edition however even if I do that I am still stuck with some missing information. Eg. Oracle also has 'Standard One' & 'Standard' edition databases however I do not know how to map those to my original engine values.